# Go back to last page on another tab JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browser, next.js

I have a back button on a nextJS repo, that when clicked, I can call `handleClick`

```js
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
...
const router = useRouter();
const handleClick = e => {
   router.back();
}
```

And it works fine. But I'll like to go to previous page on a new tab if the user pressed down the control key before clicking my back button. And I can detect the control key part but don't know how to navigate to previous page on a new tab

```js
const handleClick = e => {
   if (e.ctrlKey) {
       // go back on another tab
   }
   else
      router.back();
}
```

I'm looking for a solution in JS (or specific to NextJS)

Answer (score 1):

One solution is not to use JS, but to use a html link pointing to the URL of the last page. You can obtain the URL using the `document.referrer` property. Here is how you can create a back button in pure JS:

```
a = document.createElement('a')
a.text = "Go back"
a.href = document.referrer
document.body.append(a)
```

Comment: I considered using `document.referrer` but my app is a react SPA and the value of `referrer` is not accurate when I console.log it

Comment: You can probably obtain the correct URL from the React router.

Comment: How do I do that? I know you can do `props.history.pop()` to go to previous page, but I doubt you can directly access the url of that previous page